Burninate [sa], [root], and [administrator]?
Should we burninate (delete) these tags?



Tag
Questions
Created On




sa
5
May 6, 2021


root
15
May 21, 2020


administrator
4
March 13, 2024



Some considerations.

None of these tags has any usage guidance
All of the questions using these tags have other clarifying tags
In every case, it appears a well-intentioned user with sufficient priveleges created the tag; but that most or all subsequent usage has been done by newer and greener posters


Very related: [Can we burninate the truncation] tag

In my opinion, burninating a tag should be reserved for tags that are causing a current and ongoing problem around usability of the site.
My vote would be to leave them in since the harm of doing so is quite negligible.
This does not preclude tidiness-minded users from performing normal cleanup of low-value, low-volume tags; it is rather to say that burnination specifically is reserved for problematic cases instead of normal housekeeping.
